# Kurento: Does rtcPeer.videoEnabled = false stops the streaming

Tags: kurento

Does the following code stop the actual stream going from user to KMS?

participants[user].rtcPeer.videoEnabled = false;

When I checked into Chrome webrtcinternals, I don't see receiving packets from this peer, but wireshark does show some traffic.

-Thanks,

Comment: Don´t forget to mark the question as answered, please.

Comment: Yes. Did that. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you issue this line

```
 setTimeout(function() { webRtcPeer.videoEnabled = false } , 60000);
```

in the callback where the answer from a WebRTC negotiation is processed ([here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-hello-world/src/main/resources/static/js/index.js#L121), for instance), you'll see that the video stops.

[image]

What chrome is doing right now is sending a black video, that's why you see some traffic going on.

Comment: Ok. So because my camera is still being accessed, it is sending a blank stream?

So, If I want to turn off my camera, i will need to dispose the current rtc peer, define local constrains again and do the negotiation?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The camera hasn't been released, and will not be unless you `stop` the local stream that you got from getUserMedia.

Comment: What about Firefox, IE and Safari. Do they also keep sending black video?

Comment: @AmrutaAgnihotri IE and Safari don't have WebRTC. As of FF, I don't remember what they do as it's been a while since I don't check that. The best thing you can do is test it ;-)